# How to refer to shapes in a module

Tags: vba, excel

I have created different shapes in excel and have assigned a macro to it which functions as activating another sheet. I want to put all these under one macro and then assign it to different shapes with different linking property. But this code doesn't work because obviously I am doing something stupid. Can someone please help?

```
Dim shp As ShapeRange, ws As Sheets, i As Integer
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Introduction", "S1 Fuel Consumption", "S1 Fugitive", "S2 Electricity Consumption"))
Set shp = ws(2).Shapes.Range(Array("Chevron1", "Chevron2"))

Select Case shp(i)

Case shp(1)
ws(1).Activate

Case shp(2)
ws(3).Activate

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: `It just executes the second "with"` - it always executes first `with` statement and after that - second. It's a normal program flow. Do you understand what `with` statement actially do?

Comment: Ohh yes you are right.. It will work in a flow. Then how can I assign it to different shapes but within one macro?

Comment: Can you help me by giving a sample code? Because I am very new to VBA so I don't know most of the functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much easier way to do "buttons" in VBA (I assume this is what your trying to achieve)

First off, in a module, create the "Open Worksheet" code:

```
Sub Open_Sheet2
Sheets("Sheet2").visible = True
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
End Sub
```

Then right click your shape, choose `Assign Macro` and assign `Open_Sheet2` to that shape. Now when it is clicked, it will open Sheet2

Comment: Hey yes I want to work with buttons, but I have 10 to 15 such buttons. So I was wondering if I could just put everything under one code.

Comment: It's personal preference, but I would just but all of the "Open" Subs in a Module dedicated to holding just those subs. Then you know where they all are. It's quick, easy and you only call it when you need it

Comment: What does the .visible code line do ? I mean I am able to execute the sheet activation without that code line.. So I was wondering..

Comment: The `. Visible` ensures that if the sheet is hidden, it is unhidden to ensure that the activation works without fault